# java.lang.NullPointerException error while accessing method from array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm just stuck on error "*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException*"
Please tell me the mistake I'm committing, with solution. its a simple array. How i can access the method setAge(int) from this array.

```
    Person arr[] = new Person[2];

    arr[0].setAge(20);
```

Thanks.

Comment: fill your array first..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating an array with two empty slots. Populate these slots first:

```
arr[0] = new Person();
arr[1] = new Person();
```

Or for a big array use a loop:

```
for(int personIndex = 0; personIndex < arr.size; personIndex++)
{
    arr[personIndex] = new Person();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize any of the objects in your array.

```
arr[0] = new Person();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized array of persons. First initialize object of array like this

```
 Person arr[] = new Person [2];
 arr[0]=new Person ();
 arr[1]=new Person ();
```

Now set age of person :-

```
 arr[0].setAge(20);
 arr[1].setAge(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

new Person[2] creates an array which can hold two person objects at arr[0] and arr[1] (basically equal to null).But you have not initialized arr[0] to a new Person object at each location. So when try to set value for the object locating at arr[0] you are trying to set the age to a null object which throws you a null pointer exception..